# The best way to sync files between Windows and Windows Phone using OneDrive

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, onedrive

I've implemented OneDrive into my Universal App and it seems to work but I struggle about how to sync files between devices.

Let's say I got save, stats and current game state files separately. They are not big but greater than 100Kb so I can's use roaming folder.
I was thinking about using roaming settings so if there are changes I just check the value of it (date and time e.g.) the last change was made and if it differs then just display a notification that user should synchronize his files (MS requirement is that you can't automatically sync files with OneDrive - user must click sync button). And what if roaming settings were removed after 30 days interval?

Is this the best solution or I should not use OneDrive? I don't have any web service and I don't think I have time to learn how to make one properly (but if it isn't that hard I might try and abandon OneDrive). I think Using roaming settings is good idea. Set one to notify if there were changes (and one local to preserve previous value) and few more to notify which files were changed.

**EDIT:**
I changed the way I do it and now there is no need to check which files are the newest (I check the content and join them together) but still there is one thing to do.
How to sync files with OneDrive within `OnSuspending` method that it still will upload them even if App will suspend (I got 5 seconds, right?).
Or just method  `CreateBackgroundUploadAsync` method is taking care of everything and I shouldn't bother myself with this.

Comment: If you have to choose from the roaming file and OneDrive, I suggest you using the OneDrive. In the windows desktop, the roaming file is usually sync when user sign in and out. In your case, it's better to sync the file when start the app and quit the app. And I will use OneDrive REST API to download and upload the file.

Comment: Can I sync files when I start and quit an app? I remember that it shouldn't be done this way using OneDrive API. There was something that user should himself sync files (by pressing button etc.)

Comment: AFAIK there's no requirement that the user must click a "Sync" button to sync files with OneDrive. The terms of use just require that you make it clear how your app is using OneDrive. Part of that is done for you when the user consents to allowing your app to use OneDrive, but part of it can be done by your app explaining that it's storing save files in OneDrive. Using the App Folder concept in the OneDrive API would make this even better, because then the files for your app are nicely contained and your app wouldn't have access to everything else in the drive.

Comment: That's useful information. I just remember reading such thing but can't find it again or I could missunderstand it. I struggle now with syncing files while leaving an app. With Windows Phone it's easy - but takes time and I have no idea how to do it with Windows App. Maybe I should just let user sync files if necessary.